# Probability of $n$ random reals summing up less than $k$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are $n$ random numbers uniformly generated from $0$ to $1$. What is the probability of its sum less than $k$? 
For cases like $k=1$, it is easy to use the geometry method. However, the same method is no longer trivial for other values. Is there a good way to derive a general formula?

Comment: You have not mentioned if random variables are independent. Assuming independence, the general method to find density function of sum of independent random variables is to take convolution of the density functions of the random variables involved.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ iid where $X_i$ is unioform in $[0,1]$. If $n$ is big enough, $$\frac{X_1+...+X_n-n\mathbb E[X_1]}{\sqrt{nVar(X_1)}}$$

can be approximated by a $\mathcal N(0,1)$ law.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of $n$ independent $U(0,1)$ is the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution).  You can find the CDF and more on the wiki page.

Essentially, you Fourier invert the $n$-th power of the very simple characteristic function of $U(0,1)$ $\varphi(t)=\frac{\exp(it)-1}{it}$ to get the probabilty density function, hence the CDF.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the sum lies in the interval $[k,k+1]$
where $k$ is an integer is
$$\frac{A(n,k)}{n!}$$
where $A(n,k)$ is an [Eulerian number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number). So the probability that the sum is
$\le k$ for $k$ an integer is
$$\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}A(n,j).$$